# Is a set of values of an exponential function uncountable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, exponential-function

E.G. $f(x) = 2^x$

If yes, is there an easy, informal proof that a layman could understand?

Comment: Do you mean the set of functions, or the set of values? On what domain? What codomain? Either way, you could easily appeal to an argument using the real numbers using the most likely assumptions.

Comment: Thanks. I meant the set of values in the codomain. So I guess I failed to realize that the set of values in the codomain is countable, if the set of values in the domain is countable and the function maps to a countable codomain, by definition? So if we only allowed 0 and positive integers for x in the example, the set of values in the codomain is countable?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the function is defined on some domain $D \subseteq \Bbb R$. The function $f(x)=2^x$ has an inverse on $(0,\infty)\supseteq f[D]$, namely $y \to {^2}\log(y)$, so that $f$ is injective. By standard set theory this means that $|D|\le |f[D]|$, i.e. the image set is at least as large as the domain in cardinality. So yes if your domain is uncountable.